# Calling Excel from PHP 5 through COM fails on Windows 7 when Apache started through Task Planner

Tags: php, apache, windows-7, com

***Hey folks, this question can't be too complicated. Please provide a solution to at least figure out the ultimate root cause of the problem.***

I currently write an application, which **controls Excel through COM**: The app creates a COM-based Excel instance, opens some XLS files and reads their contents.

**Scenario I**

On Windows 7, I start Apache and mySQL using **xmapp-control with system administrator rights**. All works as expected. The PHP-based controller script interacts with Excel as expected.

**Scenario II**

A problem appears, if I start Apache and mySQL as 'background jobs'. Here is how:

- I created two jobs using **Windows 7 Task Planner**. One runs apache_start.bat, the other runs mysql_start.bat.
- Both tasks run as **SYSTEM with elevated privileges** when Windows 7 boots.

**Apache and mySQL work as expected.** Specifically, Apache serves HTTP request from clients and PHP is able to talk to mySQL.

When I call the PHP controller, which calls and interacts with Excel using COM, I do receive an error.

The **error message comes from Excel** [not COM itself] and reads like this:

- Excel can't read the specified Excel-file
- Excel failed to save the file due to an ill-name worksheet

Interestingly, the first during the first run of the PHP-based controller script, it takes a few seconds to render the error message. Each subsequent run immediately renders the error message.

**Windows system logs** didn't show a single problem report entry.

Note, that the **PHP program and the Apache instance didn't change** - except the way Apache was started.

At least the PHP controller **script is perfectly able to read the file-system**, since it provides the pathes to the XLS-file through scandir() of a certain directory.

**Concurrency issues can't** be the cause of the problem. A single instance of the specific PHP controller interacts with Excel.

**Question**

Could someone provide details, why this happens? Or provide ways to isolate the ultimate cause of the problem (e.g. by means of a PowerShell 2 script)?

**UPDATE-1 :: 2011-11-29**

As proposed, I switched the Task Planner job from SYSTEM to a **conventional user**. Works. Apache and MySQL get started and process request.

Unfortunately, the situation regarding Excel did't change a bit. Still, I see the error.

As assumed earlier, the EXCEL COM server starts. I'm able to change various settings (e.g. suppress dialogs) without a problem through the COM-instance.

The problem happens while calling this:

```
$excelComObject->Workbooks->Open( 'PathToXLSFile' );
```

**UPDATE-2 :: 2011-11-30**

Added the **accounts USER, GUEST and EVERYONE** with the READABLE right to the access control list of the XLS file . No change.

Modified the app in such a way, that the PHP part **creates a copy of the XLS file as a temporary file** and moves the contents of the original file into this. Just to ensure, that the problem isn't forced by odd file / path names.

**Still, the problem persists.**

**UPDATE-2 :: 2011-12-05**

I'm going to send the EXCEL COM-Server methods in such a way, that Excel creates a blank file and saves it to /tmp. Let's see, if Excel even isn't able to read this file.

Comment: Have you ever *manually* started Excel in the exact environment and with the exact user account it would have with an automated start?

Comment: Hm. You mean I should login as SYSTEM and start Excel? Can SYSTEM login as a user? In Scenarion I - Apache / MySQL running as normal logged in user - no problem appears.

Comment: I suppose that Excel has never been first-time-initialized (think HKEY_CURRENT_USER and file system paths) in the context you want to run it under (and BTW, SYSTEM is a bad context, I strongly suggest you change that to an actual user that has an own profile)

Comment: By context you mean, that SYSTEM is far too strong to run Apache / MySQL. Do you?

Comment: Primarily yes, but apart from that I'm not sure if running a desktop app as SYSTEM gives you the chance to initialize it properly. Having a dedicated account gives you a chance to establish a debugging scenario, while with SYSTEM you can't even log in to see what's wrong.  Remember that Excel might also display modal message boxes that are not visible in a server-only environment.

Comment: Running Excel in a server environment isn't supported by Microsoft, and might very well contravene the terms of your license.  I'm not the software police - I just thought you should check this before deciding whether to proceed.

Comment: Ah, OK. In fact, this application isn't user-multiplexing. Primarily, its a scheduled job, which reads a set of files and writes their contents to a DB. Thus, user never directly interact with Excel through the server.

Comment: ... and users can't even call the script, which processes Excel.

Comment: You said you are getting "an error message", and then posted *what you understood it to mean*. If you want to get to the root cause of the problem, you need to post the *actual* *relevant* code and error messages. See also [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Comment: @Martin He is running Windows 7. Nobody said anything about Windows Server. You can run WAMP with Windows 7. Your *assumptions* do not apply.

Comment: @PointedEars I verified the above error message again. At read as written above.

Comment: @PointedEars In fact, It's Windows 7 workstation. The system in question is an intermediate system with more or less no work-load. It's solely used to forward data in a well-defined and automated fashion from some zone to a less secure zone.

Comment: Assuming that the error message reads *exactly* as you say (which I still doubt), you have still not posted *all the relevant code* that caused it. So all bets are still off.

Comment: @PointedEars Erm... I saw he was running Windows 7.  You seem to answer your own point with "You can run WAMP with Windows 7".  Of course people can always try to use Windows 7 as a server if they want to.  Makes no difference to my points about support or licensing.  I think maybe your assumptions about my comment did not apply.

Comment: @Martin He is *not* "running Excel in a server environment".

Comment: @PointedEars I guess it depends how you define a server environment.  I was careful not to say "running on a server" because I thought people would misunderstand me in the way that you did.  As you said, Windows 7 can be a server environment.  Next time I'll choose my words better.  I guess our combined comments here will now ensure that nobody remains confused on the subject.  Thankfully, Stefan appeared to understand me just fine.

Comment: @Martin Please provide proof that this cannot work with WAMP?

Comment: @StefanPantke JFYI: Windows 7 is an OS designed for workstations. The server equivalent is Windows Server 2008 R2. But I do not think that is relevant here.

Comment: Far from providing proof this cannot work, I can offer confirmation that it _does_ work.  That doesn't affect its supportability or whether it contravenes license terms though.  @Stefan please accept my apologies for this pointless stream of argument.  I trust you can see that my original comment was well-meant, even if it doesn't apply to you.

Comment: @Martin Please provide proof then that this is not supported or contravenes license terms. Otherwise your statements here are merely [FUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fear,_uncertainty,_and_doubt).  Barring further evidence from you, one *is* *allowed* to install Apache, MySQL, PHP *and* Excel on a Windows 7 box (Excel only if you licensed it, of course). One is *allowed* to use COM with PHP, and as you say yourself, it is also technically possible. So what was *your* point with regard to the question?

Comment: @Martin No problem Martin. I appreciate each and any hint!

Comment: @SeveralAuthors If the app runs on Win 7 Workstation or Server doesn't matter here. Behavior is identical ob both systems regarding the specific problem.

Comment: @PointedEars More or less any license agreement denies using client-site applications in a fashion, that several users can interact with a single instance. As far as I know, this scenario is call user-muliplexing. As stated earlier, this application doesn't multiplex. No user interacts with Excel. A single PHP process does its job started by a scheduler.

Comment: Supportability discussed here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757.  For licensing I think you're ok so long as any user would could use Excel via your server has a license to run Excel themselves, but I'm not a lawyer so if any reader cares about this they should check the EULA themselves.

Comment: @Martin Once again - and now for the last time: Neither the user has accesses to Excel, nor multiple instances of Excel do ever run. Excel runs fully decoupled from a user session. Once instance of Excel. All users interact with data read from a DBMS - and the Excel-COM server not even runs on the user-accessible front-end web-server.

Comment: @Martin Thanks for the KB-article. I was aware of a similar one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the past (read: pre Vista) services had an option called "Allow Service to interact with desktop" which allowed services to spawn windows etc.  Starting Vista, this is no longer allowed.

I suspect Excel is failing because it can't function under this restriction.  Thus, any attempt to run it as a service in your Win7 installation will fail.

You can Windows XP and allow desktop interaction for your Apache process, which I don't really recommend for obvious reasons.

Another approach I would take is to create a PHP script that runs as a regular process and listens on a socket in an infinite loop.  Your PHP script that runs under Apache would communicate with the secondary script through the local socket and have the secondary script spawn Excel.

This may sound complicated but in fact it's not a lot of code and it fixes a problem you will soon have anyway: You should only have one instance of Excel running or you may run into problems.  The secondary script could queue requests, handing off one by one to Excel then taking the next in the queue.

Comment: Your explanation sounds reasonable. Thx for that! Did you read the point, that Excel in fact starts as COM-server? I'm able to interact with the Excel-instance. Just opening an XLS-files fails. Regarding this situation: Does you answer still apply?

Comment: Hard to say.  It does sound like a security related issue (which I think you already tried to address in various ways) but I think at the end of the day if you solve that you'll have others.  Microsoft has some more details here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757

Answer (score 3):

Go into the task planner and let everything run as a local user. This will probably require that you enter a password so create one if you don't have one already.

Excel is a user-level application that shouldn't run as SYSTEM. I'm sure there are ways around it, but you should simply let everything run at the correct level.

Having Apache run on the user level isn't a problem.

Comment: Actually, yeah, those two are pretty similar :-)

Comment: *"Having Apache run on the user level isn't a problem."* - it's actually recommended, I'm pretty sure. :)

Comment: Switched to standard user in task planner. The problem persists.

Answer (score 2):

Try creating the following directories:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Config\Systemprofile\Desktop

C:\Windows\System32\Config\Systemprofile\Desktop
```

it worked for me :-)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/innovateonoffice/thread/b81a3c4e-62db-488b-af06-44421818ef91

Comment: What does it adds to the current accepted answer, other than "it worked for me" commentary?

Comment: This worked for me too, please upvote this answer. The root cause is that Excel is a desktop application that is not designed to work from a system service account, and it seems to require this specific dirs. I had the exact same problem as described on the MSDN page and tried several other 'solutions' before stumbling on this one. No further operation was required (registry, DCOM registration, etc) other than creating the Desktop folders.